# Using string methods in a SELECT query to select up to the second space?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, select

In an MS-Access database I'm working with, one of the tables has a field called "Name". The format of this field will generally be along the lines of "firstname surname integer", but sometimes may just be "firstname surname".

I need to select just the first name and the surname from the name field.

I've looked at using the Left function

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT([Name], x)
```

However since names are different lengths, this isn't going to work since there is no constant integer to use as the second parameter. Nor can it be used with

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(InStr([Name], " "), x)
```

for the above reason, but also because because that would split the field at the first space.

Is there a way using `LEFT`, `TRIM`, `SPLIT` or any other string manipulation that I can create a query to select just the first two parts of the name? I need the space included.

Comment: what is` separator` between first name and surname , a `,`or a character or empty space

Comment: @BHouse Sorry, it's a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf( ( InStr( InStr([Name],' ') + 1 , [Name], ' ') > 0 ), Left( [Name], InStr(InStr([Name],' ') + 1 , [Name], ' ') ), [Name]) 
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Wow, what an answer this is! Thanks so much, that's perfect! My mind has been blown